# What is the OS version for Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, winapi, version

What is the internal version for the upcoming Windows 8.1?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> Windows XP =  5.1
>   Windows 7 =   6.1
>   Windows 8 =   6.2

But Windows 8.1 ?

I was unable to find any helpful information so far...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version is **6.3**, but apps not targeted for Windows 8.1 will get 6.2

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302074(v=vs.85).aspx